# Using tables in the layout

Tags: html, css, html-table

Recently I learned that it's often discouraged to use tables in webpage layout ([source](http://webdesign.about.com/od/layout/a/aa111102a.htm))

I've already made my web application and some of its parts are based on table layout.
For example, my main page consists of a list of photos (similar to some Tumblr layouts) within a table. The table has a single column and multiple rows, each of which has information about each picture.

I wonder if I should try to fix some of my layout to make it fit to the standard or not. Also, aside from the *table issue* I want to hear about your opinions if there are some major issues with the way I made my entire webpage layout.

**UPDATE:** This is how I'm using tables in my webpage. Could anyone help me how it should be changed?

```
<% posts.each do %>
  <div class="post">
    <table>
      <tr><!-- title, name, date -->
        <td><%= post.title %></td>
        <td><%= user.name %></td>
        <td><%= date %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr><!-- image -->
        <td><%= image %></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Why on earth would you make a table with only one column?

Comment: Why is this question getting down votes? I thought using tables was a viable option to do what I wanted to do, and if it's wrong, I expected someone would nicely point it out and advise how to rearrange and what kind of approach I should use...

Comment: Because we have a few too many people on that react on emotion instead of helping out stackoverflow's visitors. They see "table" and "layout" in one sentence and hit the downvote button. Not even explaining why in a comment. I upvoted your question to compensate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've already built your pages using a table, just keep using it. You will get no advantage of switching to a no-table based layout aside perhaps a little better maintainability.

If you build a new site (or decide to switch to a table-less layout) just use the following:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">Content of row 1</div>
    <div class="row">Content of row 2</div>
    <div class="row">Content of row 3</div>
</div>
```

With some css like:

```
div.container {
    width: 800px;
}

div.row {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

It will give you a much cleaner html source, since you lose all the `<tr><td></td></tr>` stuff, and since your content isn't tabular data, divs are the right elements to use for what you are doing.

Comment: thank you for your input Damien. Could you check my update?

Comment: Never mind. I get it. I should just replace all the table rows with div, and position the cell contents accordingly after. Thanks!

Comment: I was just looking at it, but you indeed got it :) Goodluck!